# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Did any US president win elections without extensive campaigning?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2030/did-any-us-president-win-elections-without-extensive-campaigning)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How often does Senator McCain vote against his own party?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/how-often-does-senator-mccain-vote-against-his-own-party)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why does the United States begin its fiscal year on October 1st?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2072/why-does-the-united-states-begin-its-fiscal-year-on-october-1st)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does it mean when a party has a mandate?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/what-does-it-mean-when-a-party-has-a-mandate)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Will government workers furloughed during the shutdown be paid later?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/will-government-workers-furloughed-during-the-shutdown-be-paid-later)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Why is the Speaker of the House able to stop a vote on a clean spending bill?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2145/why-is-the-speaker-of-the-house-able-to-stop-a-vote-on-a-clean-spending-bill)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does the ACA penalize individuals for not being able to afford insurance?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/does-the-aca-penalize-individuals-for-not-being-able-to-afford-insurance)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What are the reasons for opposing the Affordable Care Act?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/what-are-the-reasons-for-opposing-the-affordable-care-act)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What estimates are there on the level of fraud in the Social Security Disability Insurance program?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/what-estimates-are-there-on-the-level-of-fraud-in-the-social-security-disability)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Why did the US government let Lehman Brothers go bankrupt and not other Wall Street banks?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/why-did-the-us-government-let-lehman-brothers-go-bankrupt-and-not-other-wall-str)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)

---